# How to change angle of line in customized legend in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend-properties

I'm trying to add a customized legend to my ggplot but the legend boxes have lines at an angle. I want to change that angle to 0 degrees. Is there any way to do that? Following is the code for an example plot.

```
ggplot()+geom_abline(aes(color="black",,slope=1,intercept = 0))+
   geom_abline(aes(color="red",slope=0.5,intercept = 0))+
   scale_color_manual(values=c("black"="black","red"="red"))
```

We can see that the lines in the legend boxes are slightly inclined and I want to make them horizontal.
[image]

Comment: Use `geom_line` instead of `geom_abline` and calculate point pairs from intercept and slope.

Comment: @Roland I could do that but I'm plotting multiple lines from various regressions and so I'm trying to figure out if there are any convenient features that I could exploit, like `override.aes` or something else..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can change how the lines are drawn in the key: I changed `y0` and `y1` of the segmentsGrob, so that they are in the center (=0.5). (ps have a look at `GeomAbline$draw_key` before you change it)

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

GeomAbline$draw_key <- function(data, params, size) 
{
    segmentsGrob(0, 0.5, 1, 0.5, gp = gpar(col = alpha(data$colour, 
        data$alpha), lwd = data$size * .pt, lty = data$linetype, 
        lineend = "butt"))
}  

ggplot() + geom_abline(aes(color="black",slope=1,intercept = 0))+
   geom_abline(aes(color="red",slope=0.5,intercept = 0))+
   scale_color_manual(values=c("black"="black","red"="red"))
```

Comment: Thanks.  [I add to replace data$size by 0.5 to have it work]