# How to rotate legend symbols in ggplot2?

Tags: r, plot, graph, graphics, ggplot2

Consider for example this plot using the data `mtcars` and the function `coord_flip`

```
library(ggplot2)
library(Hmisc)

ggplot(mtcars,aes(x=gear,y=cyl)) + stat_summary(aes(color=as.factor(rep(1:2,16))),
fun.data=mean_cl_boot, position=position_dodge(0.4)) + coord_flip()
```

[image]

The fact that error bars are horizontal on the graph but vertical in the legend bothers me :) How can I rotate these symbols?

Comment: Raise a GitHub issue and wait till Hadley gets another intern. Better, write a pull request.

Comment: perhaps useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35703983/how-to-change-angle-of-line-in-customized-legend-in-ggplot2

Comment: The symbol should flip by default when we use coord_flip(), but anyway this function should be easily editable by users.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not coming up with an answer that works within the normal ggplot2 workflow, so for now, here's a hacky answer. Turn off the `stat_summary` legend. Then, add point and line geoms with data that is outside the range of the actual data you want to plot. This will create the point and horizontal line legend that you want. Then set the plot axis limits to include only the range of your real data, so that the fake data points are not visible.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=gear, y=cyl, color=as.factor(rep(1:2,16)))) + 
  stat_summary(fun.data=mean_cl_boot, position=position_dodge(0.4), show.legend=FALSE) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=cyl-100)) +
  geom_point(aes(y=cyl-100), size=2.5) +
  coord_flip(ylim=range(mtcars$cyl))
```

[image]

Another option would be to rotate the legend-key grobs by 90 degrees using grid functions, but I'll leave that for someone who's more skilled with `grid` than I am.

Answer (score 12):

Tweak the legend key

```
GeomPointrange$draw_key <-  function (data, params, size)     {

         draw_key_vpath <- function (data, params, size) {
           # only need to change the x&y coords so that the line is horizontal
           # originally, the vertical line was `0.5, 0.1, 0.5, 0.9`
              segmentsGrob(0.1, 0.5, 0.9, 0.5, 
              gp = gpar(col = alpha(data$colour, data$alpha), 
              lwd = data$size * .pt, lty = data$linetype, 
              lineend = "butt"), arrow = params$arrow)
              }

    grobTree(draw_key_vpath(data, params, size), 
             draw_key_point(transform(data, size = data$size * 4), params))
}
```

Then plot

```
 ggplot(mtcars,aes(x=gear,y=cyl)) + 
    stat_summary(aes(color=as.factor(rep(1:2,16))),
                  fun.data=mean_cl_boot, position=position_dodge(0.4)) + 
    coord_flip()
```

Answer (score 5):

### updated answer

`ggplot2` 3.3.0 fixed this. Using the `geom_pointrange()` function will render horizontal error bars in the legend when using the `xmin` and `xmax` args:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df <- mtcars |> 
  mutate(gear = as.factor(gear),
         am = as.factor(am)) |> 
  group_by(gear, am) |> 
  summarise(cyl_mean = mean(cyl),
            cyl_upr =  mean(cyl) + sd(cyl)/sqrt(length(cyl)),
            cyl_lwr = mean(cyl) - sd(cyl)/sqrt(length(cyl)))

ggplot(df, 
       aes(x=cyl_mean, y=gear, 
           color = am, group = am)) +
  geom_pointrange(aes(xmin = cyl_lwr,
                      xmax = cyl_upr),
                  position = position_dodge(0.25))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-05-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

### old answer

The `ggstance` package provides an easy to implement solution here:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggstance)

ggplot(mtcars,aes(x=cyl,y=gear)) + stat_summaryh(aes(color=as.factor(rep(1:2,16))),
                                                fun.data=mean_cl_boot_h, position = position_dodgev(height = 0.4))
```

[image: errorbars]

or as a `geom`:

```r
df <- data.frame(x = 1:3, y = 1:3)
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, colour = factor(x))) +
     geom_pointrangeh(aes(xmin = x - 1, xmax = x + 1))
```

Comment: You could explain better, but +1 for the good solution!

Answer (score 3):

Following up @eipi10's suggestion to use `grid` functions to edit the grobs - the relevant grobs are segments. There are two possibilities: 1) rotate the segment grobs; or 2) edit the x and y coordinates of the endpoints of the segment grobs.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(Hmisc)

library(grid)

p = ggplot(mtcars,aes(x=gear,y=cyl)) + 
    stat_summary(aes(color=as.factor(rep(1:2,16))),
                  fun.data=mean_cl_boot, position=position_dodge(0.4)) + 
    coord_flip()

g = ggplotGrob(p)

# Get names of segment grobs
grid.ls(grid.force(g))$name   # "GRID.segments"

# Check the structure of the segment grobs
str(getGrob(grid.force(g), gPath("GRID.segments"), grep = TRUE, global = TRUE))

# Edit the segment grobs using the editGrob() function
# 1) Rotate the segments
    g <- editGrob(grid.force(g), gPath("GRID.segments"), grep = TRUE, global = TRUE,
        vp = viewport(angle = 90)) 

# 2) set end points of segments
#    g <- editGrob(grid.force(g), gPath("GRID.segments"), grep = TRUE, global = TRUE,  
#         x0 = unit(0.1, "npc"), y0 = unit(0.5, "npc"), x1 = unit(0.9, "npc"), y1 = unit(0.5, "npc"))

# Draw it
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g)
```

Answer (score 1):

Edited from: https://gist.github.com/grantmcdermott/d86af2b8f21f4082595c0e717eea5a90

The main point is to use `geom_pointrangeh` from `ggstance` and remember to specify `aes` w.r.t. x-axis.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
library(hrbrthemes) 
library('ggstance')
library('jtools')

df = 
  mtcars %>%
  mutate(vs = factor(vs), am = factor(am))

fit1 = lm(mpg ~ vs * am * wt, data = df) 
fit1_coefs = tidy(fit1, conf.int = T) 

fit2 = lm(mpg ~ vs / am / wt, data = df)
fit2_coefs = tidy(fit2, conf.int = T) 


bind_rows(
  fit1_coefs %>% mutate(model = "Model 1"),
  fit2_coefs %>% mutate(model = "Model 2")
) %>%
  filter(grepl("wt", term)) %>%
  ## Optional regexp work to make plot look nicier  
  mutate(
    am = ifelse(grepl("am1", term), "Automatic", "Manual"),
    vs = ifelse(grepl("vs1", term), "V-shaped", "Straight"),
    x_lab = paste(am, vs, sep="\n")
  ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(col = model,y=x_lab, x=estimate, xmin=conf.low, xmax=conf.high)) +
  geom_pointrangeh(position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, col = "black",lty=4) +
    labs(x = NULL, y = NULL,title = "Title") +
  theme_nice() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

[image]