# How do I make the lines in a ggplot legend horizontal?

Tags: r, ggplot2

When using `geom_pointrange` the legend always displays vertical lines, even when the lines in the actual plot are horizontal. For example

```
ggplot(ToothGrowth, 
       aes(x = len, y = dose, xmin = len + 5, xmax = len - 5, color = supp)) +
  geom_pointrange(position = position_dodge2(width = 1))
```

produces
[image]

I would like to make the lines in the legend next to "OJ" and "VC" run horizontally to match the plot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to rotate legend symbols in ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40229263/how-to-rotate-legend-symbols-in-ggplot2)

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40229263/how-to-rotate-legend-symbols-in-ggplot2) answer your question?