# How to change the orientation of the "Key" of a Legend in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

How can I change the key of the caption below so that it is in the horizontal position without changing the vertical lines of the graph.

```
set.seed(000)
m <- matrix(rnorm(100,0,1),100,1)
dt <- data.frame(m)
names(dt) <- c("X")

library(ggplot2)

g2 <- ggplot(dt, aes(x=X)) 
g2 <- g2+geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..),      # Histogram with density instead of count on y-axis
                        binwidth=.5,
                        colour="black", fill="white",breaks=seq(-2, 2, by = 0.1)) 
g2 <- g2+geom_density(alpha=.3, fill="#cccccc") # Overlay with transparent density plot
g2 <- g2+  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=0, linetype="Valor Verdadeiro"),show.legend =TRUE)
g2 <- g2+  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=mean(dt$X, na.rm=T),    linetype="Valor Estimado"),show.legend =TRUE)
g2 <- g2+  scale_linetype_manual(values=c("dotdash","solid")) # Overlay with transparent density plot
g2 <- g2+  xlab(expression(paste(gamma[1])))+ylab("Densidade")
g2 <- g2+  theme(legend.key.height = unit(2, "cm") ,
                 legend.position = c(0.95, 0.95),
                 legend.justification = c("right", "top"),
                 legend.box.just = "right",
                 legend.margin = margin(6, 6, 6, 6),
                 legend.title=element_blank(),
                 legend.direction = "vertical",
                 legend.background = element_rect(fill="gray", size=.5, linetype="dotted"))
g2 <- g2+ guides(linetype = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 1)))
g2
```

Note: I want to rotate the line from within the caption that is in `dotdash` and `solid` format.

[image]

Comment: You might want to check this solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35703983/how-to-change-angle-of-line-in-customized-legend-in-ggplot2

Comment: @JeroenBoeye It does not work, I've tried!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have to resort to working with the ggplot grob and use `grid` editing functions.

```
# Your data and plot
set.seed(000)
m <- matrix(rnorm(100,0,1),100,1)
dt <- data.frame(m)
names(dt) <- c("X")

library(ggplot2)

g2 <- ggplot(dt, aes(x=X)) 
g2 <- g2+geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..),      # Histogram with density instead of count on y-axis
                        binwidth=.5,
                        colour="black", fill="white",breaks=seq(-2, 2, by = 0.1)) 
g2 <- g2+geom_density(alpha=.3, fill="#cccccc") # Overlay with transparent density plot
g2 <- g2+  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=0, linetype="Valor Verdadeiro"),show.legend =TRUE)
g2 <- g2+  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=mean(dt$X, na.rm=T),    linetype="Valor Estimado"),show.legend =TRUE)
g2 <- g2+  scale_linetype_manual(values=c("dotdash","solid")) # Overlay with transparent density plot
g2 <- g2+  xlab(expression(paste(gamma[1])))+ylab("Densidade")
g2 <- g2+  theme(legend.key.height = unit(2, "cm") ,
                 legend.position = c(0.95, 0.95),
                 legend.justification = c("right", "top"),
                 legend.box.just = "right",
                 legend.margin = margin(6, 6, 6, 6),
                 legend.title=element_blank(),
                 legend.direction = "vertical",
                 legend.background = element_rect(fill="gray", size=.5, linetype="dotted"))
g2 <- g2+ guides(linetype = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 1)))


# Adjust key height and width
g2 = g2 + theme(
   legend.key.height = unit(.6, "cm"),
   legend.key.width = unit(1, "cm"))

# Get the ggplot Grob
  gt = ggplotGrob(g2)

# grid::grid.ls(grid.force(gt))  # To get a list of editable grobs

# Edit the relevant keys
library(grid)
 gt <- editGrob(grid.force(gt), gPath("key-[3,4]-1-[1,2]"), 
        grep = TRUE, global = TRUE,
        x0 = unit(0, "npc"), y0 = unit(0.5, "npc"), 
        x1 = unit(1, "npc"), y1 = unit(0.5, "npc")) 

# Draw it
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(gt)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! One question, if I change `legend.direction = "horizontal",` where can I change in your code to keep the key horizontal?

Comment: `grid.ls(grid.force(gt)` gives the list of editable grobs. With a horizontal legend, the relevant grobs begin with: key-1-3-1; key-1-3-2; key-1-7-1; key-1-7-2. Therefore, the gPath in the editGrob command will be: `gPath("key-1-[3,7]-[1,2]")`

Comment: Thank you very much! You helped me a lot!

Comment: I have the same problem, but this code does not work to me

Comment: @iago The code works for me - for this example. Can you be a little more specific?

Comment: I've found another solution. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

As I found [out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63765249/rotate-vertical-line-in-ggplot-legend), you can now just add `key_glyph` to the `geom_vline` call:

```
library(ggplot2)
g2 <- ggplot(dt, aes(x=X)) 
g2 <- g2+geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..),      # Histogram with density instead of count on y-axis
                        binwidth=.5,
                        colour="black", fill="white",breaks=seq(-2, 2, by = 0.1)) 
g2 <- g2+geom_density(alpha=.3, fill="#cccccc") # Overlay with transparent density plot
g2 <- g2+  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=0, linetype="Valor Verdadeiro"),show.legend =TRUE, key_glyph = "path")
g2 <- g2+  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=mean(dt$X, na.rm=T),    linetype="Valor Estimado"),show.legend =TRUE, key_glyph = "path")
g2 <- g2+  scale_linetype_manual(values=c("dotdash","solid")) # Overlay with transparent density plot
g2 <- g2+  xlab(expression(paste(gamma[1])))+ylab("Densidade")
g2 <- g2+  theme(legend.key.height = unit(2, "cm") ,
                 legend.position = c(0.95, 0.95),
                 legend.justification = c("right", "top"),
                 legend.box.just = "right",
                 legend.margin = margin(6, 6, 6, 6),
                 legend.title=element_blank(),
                 legend.direction = "vertical",
                 legend.background = element_rect(fill="gray", size=.5, linetype="dotted"))
g2 <- g2+ guides(linetype = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 1)))
g2
```

[image]