# rotate vertical line in ggplot legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm looking to rotate the legend of a plot from vertical lines to horizontal but keep the actual lines vertical in the graph. There are a number of hack type [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42954248/how-to-change-the-orientation-of-the-key-of-a-legend-in-ggplot) but I think this can now easily be done with `ggstance` package but I'm not sure how to achieve it.

```
library(tidyverse) 
library(ggstance)
df <- tibble(x = rnorm(40))
df_stats <-
  df %>%  summarise(
    mean = mean(x), 
    median = median(x)
  ) %>% 
  gather(key = legend, value = value, mean:median)

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = x)) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 20) +
  geom_vline(data = df_stats, aes(xintercept = value, color = legend))
```

[image]

Any suggestions using `ggstance`? thanks

**EDIT** per @Allan Cameron comment

As `ggstance` has been superseded by the latest version of ggplot, I'm happy to see any solution someone might have?

Comment: `ggstance` has been superseded by the latest version of ggplot, as explained [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggstance/readme/README.html), so I don't think this is the correct avenue to use.

Comment: thanks for the tip. It seems `key_glyph` argument below is all that I needed!

Comment: But `ggstance` was a good pointer, because in its documentation I discovered the `key_glyph` argument :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change the `key_glyph` argument, see the available [`key_glyph`s](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/draw_key.html). You need "path":

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(x = rnorm(40))
df_stats <-
  df %>%  summarise(
    mean = mean(x), 
    median = median(x)
  ) %>% 
  gather(key = legend, value = value, mean:median)

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = x)) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 20) +
  geom_vline(data = df_stats, aes(xintercept = value, color = legend),
             key_glyph = "path")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-09-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>