# Adding the errorbar icon in legend in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, errorbar

I am plotting some time series and the error bars (`geom_errorbar`) showing the SD of the means. I am using `ggplot` and I want to make the error bars visible in the legend, like this below (done in MatLab):

[Error bar in legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGHTq.jpg)

Is it possible?

Comment: you can change the legend key function, `GeomErrorbar$draw_key` . [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35703983/how-to-change-angle-of-line-in-customized-legend-in-ggplot2/35710840#35710840) might get you started

Comment: e.g. `GeomErrorbar$draw_key  <-   function (data, params, size) {
    data$linetype[is.na(data$linetype)] <- 0 ;
    
    segmentsGrob(c(0.2, 0.2, 0.5),
                 c(0.2, 0.8, 0.2),
                 c(0.8, 0.8, 0.5),
                 c(0.2, 0.8, 0.8),
                 gp = gpar(col = alpha(data$colour, 
        data$alpha), lwd = data$size * .pt, lty = data$linetype, 
        lineend = "butt"), arrow = params$arrow)
}`

Comment: See also this https://owi.usgs.gov/blog/boxplots/